# How to show mean for a dataframe column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> head(diabetes)
  tp  gl bp  t   s   bm     p  a class .row
1  6 148 72 35   0 33.6 0.627 50     0    1
2  1  85 66 29   0 26.6 0.351 31     1    2
3  8 183 64  0   0 23.3 0.672 32     0    3
4  1  89 66 23  94 28.1 0.167 21     1    4
5  0 137 40 35 168 43.1 2.288 33     0    5
6  5 116 74  0   0 25.6 0.201 30     1    6
```

I know I can see the means for all columns with `summary(diabetes)`; however, I would like to see the means for each column as it relates to the `class` column. The class column can have only two values `0` or `1`. So I would like to see the mean for each column when the class is `0` or `1`.

For example:

```
> summary(diabetes$tp) #shows mean for tp column
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   1.000   3.000   3.845   6.000  17.000 
> summary(diabetes$tp$class==0) #my effort to show mean for tp column when class == 0
```

Comment: To achieve success with the last effort it would need to be: `summary( diabetes$tp[ tp$class==0 ])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
diabetes %>% 
       group_by(class) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(mean), -.row)
```

Or

```
aggregate(.~class, diabetes[-10], mean)
```